# Library resolution with autoconf?

Tags: autoconf

I'm building my first autoconf managed package.

However I can't find any simple examples anywhere of how to specify a required library, and find that library where it might be in various different places.

I've currently got:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(['event'], ['event_init'])
```

but:

1. It doesn't find the version installed in `/opt/local/lib`
2. It doesn't complain if the library isn't actually found
3. I need to set the include path to `/opt/local/include` too

any help, or links to decent tutorials much appreciated...

Comment: Does this [Documentation on AC\_CHECK\_LIB](http://www.shlomifish.org/lecture/Autotools/slides/common_macros/AC_CHECK_LIB.html) help at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to manually set `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` if you want gcc/g++ to look in non-standard locations.

So, before calling `AC_CHECK_LIB()`, do something like

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/opt/local/include"
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/opt/local/include"
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/opt/local/lib"
```

You don't need CXXFLAGS if you're only using gcc throughout your configure script.

Comment: I presume that first line should be CPPFLAGS, not CFLAGS?

Comment: I did mean CFLAGS in the first line, however as far as include headers go, CPPFLAGS should also do the trick.

Comment: I agree with Alnitak in the sense that it is advised to use CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS (depending on C/C++ compiler you intend to use) should only be used for compiler arguments (like "-g", "-O3"). Includes should go to CPPFLAGS (C Pre Processor).

Comment: No, No, No, No, No.  You absolutely must not assign CFLAGS in configure.ac  From the autoconf documentation: "...the package itself should never set a user variable..." "CFLAGS is one such variable."

Comment: *FLAGS may only be set temporarily in configure.ac, e.g. to cater for AC_CHECK_foo. The original value must ultimately be restored.

Answer (score 15):

autoconf script cannot guess the "optional" library locations, which may vary from one platform to another. So you can say

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib" ./configure
```

For `AC_CHECK_LIB()` you need to specify the fail condition explicitly in "action-if-false" argument:

```
dnl This is simply print "no" and continue:
AC_CHECK_LIB([m], [sqrt123])
dnl This will stop:
AC_CHECK_LIB([m], [sqrt123], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([sqrt123 was not found in libm])])
```

Output:

```
checking for sqrt123 in -lm... no
checking for sqrt123 in -lm... no
configure: error: sqrt123 was not found in libm
```

`AC_CHECK_LIB()` does not fail by default on obvious reasons: one may check for several different libraries that provide similar functionality and choose one of them :)

Also have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596536/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-detect-library-dependencies-in-a-c-c-project) for similar topic.

Comment: Better yet, `./configure CPPFLAGS=...` which will remember the variable in a subsequent `./config.status --recheck`, for example. See http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Defining-Variables.html

Answer (score 10):

If the library ships a .pc file, consider using the PKG_CHECK_MODULES() macro which does the things you want. If it's your own library, just ship a .pc file into /usr/lib/pkgconfig, it'll make it much easier for other developers to depend/use it.

Comment: My lib ships a .pc file.  Where to put the PKG_CHECK_MODULES() macro?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread now, but I guess this may help some people out. This is how I find some stuff.

```
hdff="no"
hdffprefix="ERROR"
AC_ARG_WITH(hdf,[  --with-hdf              Compile with hdf library, for output.],[hdffprefix=$withval hdff="yes"],[])
# if there is no value given, it appears tha hdffprefix is set to "yes"
if test $hdffprefix = "yes" -a $hdff = "yes"
then
    echo "HDF: Attempting to find HDF"
    hdffprefix="ERROR"

    # check if hdffprefix is set, if it is not, it sets it to "ERROR" and the 
    # 'if' comparison evaluates to true
    if [[ "$hdffprefix" == "ERROR" ]]
    then
        echo "HDF: hdffprefix not set, searching PATH"
        for i in `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`
        do
            if [[ $i == *hdf* ]]
            then
                if [[ $i == *bin/* ]]
                then
                    hdffprefix=${i%bin/}
                    # if it doesn't exist, re-set to ERROR
                    if [[ ! -f ${hdffprefix}include/hdf.h ]]
                    then
                    hdffprefix="ERROR"
                    fi
                elif [[ $i == *bin* ]]
                then
                    hdffprefix=${i%bin}
                    # if it doesn't exist, re-set to ERROR
                    if [[ ! -f ${hdffprefix}include/hdf.h ]]
                    then
                    hdffprefix="ERROR"
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        done
        if [[ "$hdffprefix" == "ERROR" ]]
        then
            echo "HDF: hdffprefix not found in PATH, trying 'which'"
            WHICH_TEST_HDF=`which hdf2gif`
            if [[ WHICH_TEST_HDF != "" ]]
            then
                hdffprefix=${WHICH_TEST_HDF%bin/hdf2gif}
            else
                echo "HDF: Warning - hdf not found"
            fi
        fi
    fi
    if [[ "$hdffprefix" != "ERROR" ]]
    then
        hdff="yes"
        echo "HDF found: $hdffprefix"
    fi
fi
if test $hdff = 'yes'; then
        hdfincs=" -DUSE_HDF -I"${hdffprefix}"include"
        scriptotherlibsinc=${scriptotherlibsinc}" -L"${hdffprefix}"/lib"
        scriptotherlibs=${scriptotherlibs}" -lmfhdf -ldf -ljpeg -lz"
    AC_CHECK_HEADERS([${hdffprefix}/include/hdf.h],,[AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find hdf.h])])
    AC_CHECK_HEADERS([${hdffprefix}/include/mfhdf.h],,[AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find mfhdf.h])])
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

```
# We need the math library for some tests.
AC_CHECK_LIB([m], [floor], [],
                  [AC_MSG_ERROR([Can't find or link to the math library.])])
```

Note that it does not automatically error out when the library is not found, you must called AC_MSG_ERROR() as in the code above.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to setup autoconf to find these directories automatically and codelogic gives the answer; but suppose you don't want to search there on all system, only on a mac. You can add the following

```
AC_CANONICAL_HOST
case $host_os in
    darwin* )
        CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/opt/local/include"
        CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/opt/local/include"
        LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/opt/local/lib"
        ;;

esac
```

Note that I added it as a case tree so that you can add things for a variety of operating systems later (such as linux* and *BSD*).

Answer (score -1):

If you are happen to be using `GCC` or `CLANG`, the standard way is having the environment variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` with the path of the non-official *includes* files and `LIBRARY_PATH` for the libraries. Remind that you do not have to change anything in the configure.ac. So you can just call the configure in this way:

```
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
$ ./configure
```

## The facto standard variables

```
Variable           | lang | Usage
-------------------|------|---------
C_INCLUDE_PATH     | C    | colon separated list of include directory paths
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH | C++  | colon separated list of include directory paths
LIBRARY_PATH       | C/C++| colon separated compiling time static linking dirs
LD_RUN_PATH        | C/C++| colon separated compiling time dynamic linking dirs
LD_LIBRARY_PATH    | C/C++| colon separated run-time dynamic linking dirs
CPPFLAGS           | C/C++| prepocessor flags
CFLAGS             | C    | Compiling flags
CXXFLAGS           | C++  | Compiling flags
LDFLAGS            | C++  | Linking flags
```

**NOTE** You can use `CPPFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`, however, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` /`LIBRARY_PATH` exactly fits your requirement. `CPPFLAGS/LDFLAGS` are for flags which can be many things but `*_PATH` are for `PATHs`

**Portability Note:** While this will work on many modern compilers, not all compilers will respect these variables. Some cross-compilers will outright ignore or overwrite them, which forces one to resort to `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` modifications as mentioned in other answers.

**SOURCE** Might the downvotes here be because of the lack of sources in my answer. Here is for `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` in **GCC**: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html

Comment: I work with lots of compilers and never have seen CPLUS_INCLUDE and LIBRARY_PATH. Instead, use CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS, which are the standard flags for building on Linux systems.

Comment: We heavily use those env variables in my project for libraries install in prefix `/usr/local`. `CPPFLAGS` is a totally different variable. in `CPPFLAGS` you will write `CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include"` which are actually the preprocessor flags not the include path such as `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`. Could you source that: standard flags for building on Linux systems.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html for the flags routinely used by autoconf/automake/libtool packages.

Comment: I see, well in your sources it indicates that autotools packages ignore `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`. It means that those env variables are left so that the user can indicate custom options to the underline compiler since they are understood by two of the main OSS compiles `GCC and `CLANG`.

Comment: I will edit my answer to specify my precondition in which my solution satisfies the question.