# configure.ac: Library and headers not usable and not present

Tags: autoconf

I have implemented a logging library in C (which I've named liblogger), and used Autotools to compile and install it. As far as I can see, the installation is correctly done, since the headers and the library itself (which I currently bundle into a static library) are installed into the appropriate directories (/usr/local/include/liblogger/ for the headers and /usr/local/lib for the .a).

Now I am trying to link another tool with that library (compiled and built also using Autotools). To check for the logging library presence, I have followed what is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751541/autoconf-including-a-static-library-newbie) to create the configure.ac file. But the resulting configure script says:

> checking /usr/local/include/liblogger/logger.h usability... no
>
> checking /usr/local/include/liblogger/logger.h presence... no
>
> checking for /usr/local/include/liblogger/logger.h... no
>
> checking for log_init in -l/usr/local/lib/liblogger.a... no

even though the named files **DO** exist.

The part of the configure.ac file where I check for the header and the library is as follows:

```
LIBLOGGER=/usr/local/lib
HEADERLOGGER=/usr/local/include/liblogger

AC_CHECK_HEADER([${HEADERLOGGER}/logger.h],
    [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_LOGGER_H], [1], [found logger.h])
    CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I${HEADERLOGGER}"])

AC_CHECK_LIB([${LIBLOGGER}/liblogger.a],
    log_init, [found liblogger.a], [], [])

AC_SUBST(LIBLOGGER)
```

Actually, if I try with:

```
AC_CHECK_FILE(
   [${HEADERLOGGER}/logger.h],
   [AC_MSG_NOTICE([Found logger.h])],
   [AC_MSG_NOTICE([Didn't find logger.h])]
   )
```

it **does** find the file.

Thanks.

Comment: are file permissions ok ?

Comment: Yes, they are (644, I even tried with 777, just in case).

Comment: The problem might reside in your configure.ac files. would it be ok for you to post some of their contents relevant to this issue ?

Comment: You should not be setting `LIBLOGGER` or `HEADERLOGGER` in the `configure.ac` of the dependent package.  Instead, just do `AC_CHECK_HEADER([logger.h])` and make sure that `-I/usr/local/include` is in CPPFLAGS and `-L/usr/local/lib` is in LDFLAGS when you run configure.  The trouble with hard coding a path in configure.ac is that it will completely break when someone puts the library somewhere else.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you for the advise. However, the problem with what you say is that (I haven't yet been able to determine why), the _configure_ script is not looking into `/usr/local/include` for the headers...

Comment: @Ginswich The configure script is not looking in `/usr/local/include` for headers because you have not told the preprocessor to look there.  You must put `-I/usr/local/include` in CPPFLAGS (or use some other mechanism).  Whatever you do, it is to be done by the user (the person who runs `configure`), not the maintainer (the person who builds `configure` via `autoconf`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not on the tool's configure.ac, but in the original logger library. When inspecting the **config.log** file generated when running the configure script, there was a line saying:

`/usr/local/include/liblogger/logger.h:22:19: fatal error: types.h: No such file or directory`

So I actually had to reorganize some dependencies in the logger library.

In fact, setting `HEADERLOGGER` to `liblogger` doesn't solve the problem, since (I don't know why), "/urs/local/include/liblogger" is not being searched for, returning

`configure: error: Couldn't find liblogger/logger.h`

(Perhaps I'm forgetting some previous AC instruction for that).

The moral: *the log files are there for a reason... :-S*

Comment: then I'm discarding my answer ;)