# Configure.ac AC_CHECK_HEADERS not finding ruby.h

Tags: ruby, build, configure, autoconf

I am trying to build some code, but find that I need to alter the configure.ac file first, as it is not searching in the correct place for the ruby headers. Today is the first day I have ever even looked at config.ac files, so there were bound to be issues when digging around in them and changing them! But yes, I am a complete newbie to these kinds of things, so apologies if this is a silly question.

On my system the `ruby.h` file is located at `/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h`, and there is actually a similarly named file at `/usr/include/ruby.h`. I'll admit that I don't know which one is correct, but either way, my configure script cannot find it.

This is the part of my configure.ac file that SHOULD be finding the right headers:

```
CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/usr/include/ruby"
AC_MSG_CHECKING([CPPFLAGS are $CPPFLAGS])
AC_CHECK_HEADER([ruby.h],
                [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_RUBY_H, 1, [has ruby.h -- ruby-dev is installed] )],
                [AC_MSG_ERROR([Sorry, you need ruby-dev (headers) installed])])
CPPFLAGS=$SAVE_CPPFLAGS
```

But this is the output I am getting:

```
checking ruby.h usability... no
checking ruby.h presence... no
checking for ruby.h... no
configure: error: Sorry, you need ruby-dev (headers) installed
```

In the `config.log` file, the following message is given:

```
configure:13689: checking ruby.h usability
configure:13689: gcc -c   -I/usr/include/ruby/ conftest.c >&5
In file included from conftest.c:69:0:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:24:25: fatal error: ruby/config.h: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand what the `config.h` file it is looking for is exactly.

Also, I found a similar problem [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/autoconf@gnu.org/msg16147.html), but I tried the proposed fixes (namely specifying the path within the AC_CHECK_HEADER call), but nothing worked. I also saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216076/configure-ac-library-and-headers-not-usable-and-not-present), which makes me think that my problem MIGHT be a permissions issue, but I still don't know the purpose of the `config.h` file that the log talks about. It is nowhere to be found.

Any ideas?

Comment: You absolutely do not need or want to alter `configure.ac`.  You just need to properly specify `CPPFLAGS` when you run the configure script.

Comment: `config.h` is a file that should never be installed.  If you are locating a `ruby.h` that includes `config.h`, then you are finding the wrong `ruby.h`.  What is the value of `CPPFLAGS` when you run the `configure` script?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Oh, that is good to know that I don't have to modify this file. Also, the ruby.h file I am linking to DOES include "ruby/config.h". I edited my original post to include the error I am getting from the config script. CPPFLAGS is set to `-I/usr/include/ruby/` when I run the script, due to my modification. Originally the CPPFLAGS was set to `/usr/lib64/`

Comment: Sadly, ruby installs a `config.h` that looks like it came out of `autoheader`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that it looks like you have an incomplete installation of Ruby headers.  The Autoconf probe is fine (except that you generally shouldn't change `CPPFLAGS` in `configure.ac`, since it's reserved for the user).

The real question here is what happened to your `ruby/config.h` file.  This should be part of a normal Ruby development files installation.

It's worth noting that on Debian and Ubuntu, where some headers have been moved for multiarch (so that multiple architectures of a package can be installed at the same time), the `ruby/config.h` file, since it is architecture-dependent, has been moved to a subdirectory.  On my system, for example:

```
windlord:/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1> ls -R
.:
i486-linux/  ruby/  ruby.h

./i486-linux:
ruby/

./i486-linux/ruby:
config.h

./ruby:
backward/  dl.h        io.h         re.h     st.h     version.h
defines.h  encoding.h  missing.h    regex.h  subst.h  vm.h
digest.h   intern.h    oniguruma.h  ruby.h   util.h

./ruby/backward:
classext.h  rubyio.h  rubysig.h  st.h  util.h
```

I would therefore expect the error message that you're getting if you're trying to use a compiler that isn't multiarch-aware and therefore doesn't know to search in the `/usr/include/i486-linux` directory, and you're using a multiarch installation of Ruby.  Could that be the issue?