# Install openslide and its dependency openjpeg on ubuntu without root privileges

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, root, openslide

I am connected to a server via ssh and do not have root privileges. I ultimately need to install openslide. apt-get is not present, yum requires root privilege so I was going for make/install from the source code of openslide.

I needed to install openjpeg as a dependency however they support cmake and it requires root privelege as well at some point :/ as in their [installation guide](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

Is there any way around?

PS: I need openslide to read very large (~1.5 GB) tif files in python

Comment: "I needed to install openjpeg as a dependency however they support cmake and it requires root privelege as well at some point" - By itself, CMake doesn't require root privileges. They are required if you install the project under system-wide installation prefix, which is by default. You may change installation prefix with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable, it is noted in the [guide](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md) you refer to.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked this way.

Comment: Now openslide can't find openjpeg libraries. I am not familiar with ubuntu coding, any suggestions how to specify openjpeg location for openslide?

Comment: When build `openslide`, you need to specify installation prefix used for `openjpeg` in the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable: since the prefix is no longer a default one, CMake needs a hint for using this prefix when search the library.

Comment: I couldn't find where to specify it. Thanks though

Comment: Oh, [openslide](https://github.com/openslide/openslide) seems do not use CMake for build. Then `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is not applicable for it. You need to somehow hint autotools about your openjpeg installation prefix.

Comment: Can it be somewhere here? https://github.com/openslide/openslide/blob/master/configure.ac

Comment: I am not so familiar with autotools for understand its `configure.ac`. But this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517580/library-resolution-with-autoconf) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: You have been so kind and helpful Tsyvarev, thanks so much. I will try right away

Comment: typing export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/openjpeg/lib/pkgconfig directly at the command line to speficy pkgconfig file of openjpeg worked. Thanks very much for your help.

https://lists.andrew.cmu.edu/pipermail/openslide-users/2014-May/000788.html

Comment: For future reference: installing openslide-python this way is the magical solution to solve ALL problems if you have conda

https://anaconda.org/bioconda/openslide-python

Answer (score 2):

1. download openjepg from https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/releases/download/v2.3.1/openjpeg-v2.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
2. unzip the downloaded file, and modify the pkgconfig/libjpeg2.pc, set the “prefix” to be the correct path, so that compiler can find relevant include and lib path
3. download openslide from https://github.com/openslide/openslide/releases/download/v3.4.1/openslide-3.4.1.tar.gz
4. unzip the downloaded file, and cd into the unziped folder
5. run ./configure -prefix=/the/path/you/would/like/openslide/to/be/installed PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/the/path/you/save/openjpeg/openjpeg-v2.3.1-linux-x86_64/lib/pkgconfig
6. run make & make install
7. add /the/path/you/would/like/openslide/to/be/installed/lib into “LD_LIBRARY_PATH” 
   (vi ~/.bashrc, add export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/the/path/you/would/like/openslide/to/be/installed/lib)